# Uninitialized constant for my job ActiveJob

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to learn ActiveJob and I created a simple job to walk through the process.  I'm pretty much stuck on step 1.  I've got a my_job.rb file in app/jobs.  That file contains this code:

```
class MyJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default

  def perform(obj)
    puts obj
  end
end
```

If I go to my console and type in MyJob, it acts like the class doesn't exist...what am I missing?

:001 > MyJob
NameError: uninitialized constant MyJob

Answer (score 21):

Make sure the job's filename ends with "_job.rb".

For example: a job called `CheckDropboxAvailableSpaceJob` should have its filename named `check_dropbox_available_space_job.rb`, not `check_dropbox_available_space.rb`.

Rails won't recognize it as a job if the filename doesn't have "_job" on the end.

Comment: you saved me time, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think this was resolved somewhat randomly...I probably restarted my server or something. As far as I can tell, every time a job is edited, the server has to be restarted in order for the changes to be picked up.

Comment: Had the same error, changed nothing, restarted the server and it was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I had to restart sidekiq too, in case you are using it.